# element of array not found

Tags: javascript, arrays, socket.io

I have code to receive the object `object` and check if the value of property `object.bedrijfsnaam` is already in an array I declared before, called `bedrijfsnamen`. Object.bedrijfsnamen in fact **is** inside the array already, but unfortunately Javascript doesn't see that. I've tried `bedrijfsnaam in object` besides `bedrijfsnamen.indexOf(bedrijfsnaam)!=-1`, but they both don't work. I don't get the problem.
Anyone with decent Javascript knowledge who sees the problem?

socket.io version 2.1.1

```
//The data inside my event: object 'object', with property 'object.bedrijfsnaam', which has the value 'a' (but is not a string yet)
socket.on('event', function(object){
    //stringifying the data
    var bedrijfsnaam = "'"+object.bedrijfsnaam+"'";
    console.log(bedrijfsnaam);
    //output: 'a'

    if(bedrijfsnamen.indexOf(bedrijfsnaam)!=-1){
        console.log('yes');
    }else {
        console.log('no')
    }
    //output: yes

    console.log(bedrijfsnamen);
    //output: [ 'a', 'a' ]
});
```

Comment: `'a' !== "'a'"`

Comment: @epascarello how could i make 'a' out of it?